# Multiple PNG sequences as overlays at different time points with FFMPEG

Tags: windows-10, video, ffmpeg, overlay

I'm trying to overlay three different PNG sequences at different time points in a video.
The first sequence is working as intended. It animates between 0 and 4 sec.
From 4 to 8 sec. I see only the last frame of the second sequence and from 8 to 12 sec. there is only the last frame of the third sequence.
All three sequences are 100 frames.

Any ideas?

This is what I have been trying:

```
"C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i %1 ^
-start_number 0 -i "C:\Users\ojan\Documents\2017 Lukker\Vandmaerke_Start\Vandmaerke_Start_%%03d.png" ^
-start_number 0 -i "C:\Users\ojan\Documents\2017 Lukker\Vandmaerke_Midt\Vandmaerke_Midt_%%03d.png" ^
-start_number 0 -i "C:\Users\ojan\Documents\2017 Lukker\Vandmaerke_End\Vandmaerke_End_%%03d.png" ^
-filter_complex ^
"[0:v][1:v]overlay=enable='between(t,0,4)' [temp0]; ^
[temp0][2:v]overlay=enable='between(t,4,8)' [temp1]; ^
[temp1][3:v]overlay=enable='between(t,8,12)' [out]" -map [out] -map 0:a -c:a copy "C:\Users\ojan\Documents\2017 Lukker\output.mp4"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i %1 ^
-start_number 0 -i "C:\Users\ojan\Documents\2017 Lukker\Vandmaerke_Start\Vandmaerke_Start_%%03d.png" ^
-start_number 0 -itsoffset 4 -i "C:\Users\ojan\Documents\2017 Lukker\Vandmaerke_Midt\Vandmaerke_Midt_%%03d.png" ^
-start_number 0 -itsoffset 8 -i "C:\Users\ojan\Documents\2017 Lukker\Vandmaerke_End\Vandmaerke_End_%%03d.png" ^
-filter_complex ^
"[0:v][1:v]overlay=enable='between(t,0,4)' [temp0]; ^
[temp0][2:v]overlay=enable='between(t,4,8)' [temp1]; ^
[temp1][3:v]overlay=enable='between(t,8,12)' [out]" -map [out] -map 0:a -c:a copy "C:\Users\ojan\Documents\2017 Lukker\output.mp4"
```

FFmpeg is built to work with files containing timed samples. `overlay` filter uses frame pairs (BG/FG) as per corresponding timestamps. `-itsoffset X` offsets the timestamps contained in video or generated by ffmpeg (like for image sequences) by X seconds.